# Enum с пробелами в java

Tags: java

Нужно создать перечисления с названиями компаний, но эти названия состоят из нескольких слов, а использовать пробелы нельзя... Как быть?

И например "20th Century Fox" содержит в начале цифру, с которой тоже не могут начинаться элементы перечисления.

Comment: Скажите, для чего вам это нужно. Покамест непонятно, чем вам не подходит просто набор строк.

Comment: видимо человек расспробывал, что в жава можно выводить enum переменные и они выводятся "ожидаемо", а не как в плюсах в виде чисел.

Comment: Да, в Java Enum тоже можно выводить в виде чисел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а зачем юзать енум? можно в бд или в тхт хранить это дело, на крайний случай в константах,
но если очень хочется в енумах то..

```
public enum Companies{
  FOX("20th Century Fox");
  private String value;

    private Companies(String value) {
            this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: такая запись не работает, нужно реализовать конструктор?

Comment: Само собой, нужно:

    public enum Companies{
      FOX("20th Century Fox");
      
      private String company;
  
      private Companies(String comp) {
          company = comp;
      }

      public String getCompany(){
          return company;
      }
    }

Comment: ну вот, теперь после редактирования лучше, я добавил еще переопределение ToString()  теперь всё работает, спасибо :)

Comment: не `ToString()`, а `toString()` - вы тут свои шарповские замашки бросьте!