# Проблема с пробелом в enum

Tags: java, enum

ИСХОДНИК ЗДЕСЬ:
[Enum с пробелами в java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/208936/enum-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java)

Частная попытка реализации:

```
 public enum CellSign {
        X("X");
        
//        O("O");

//        None("");

        private String value;

        private CellSign(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

ВОПРОС:
Почему интерпретатор ругается на О и None и/или как их добавить?

**ЧЕМ в данном методе является Х ?**

Comment: X("X"),
        
O("O"),

None("");

Comment: ЗАПЯТАЯ! Ясно. Это же очевидно! это же ENUM! Спасибо.